# SNS catplot (Box plot) selecting only 5 data point to be displayed based on their mean

Tags: python-3.x, seaborn, boxplot

I have a sns catplot (boxplot) (click on the link below). For each time window as seen from x axis, there are multiple boxplots which correspond to 1 ID each. How can i code such that for every time window, only 5 IDs of the highest mean at the particular time are displayed for all time window? Thank you!`

```
sns.catplot('time_window', hue='ID', y='Time (ms)', data=mo_finaldf, kind="box", showfliers=False)
```

[image: Factor plot]
[image: Dataframe]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I have found an answer to my question. Basically, seaborn and Matplotlib do not have any settings for these and you have to split your dataframe on your own. What I have done is a groupby followed by a SQL join. Hope it helps anyone who has encountered the same problem in the future.

```
df_to_join = mo_finaldf.groupby(['time_window', 'ID']).agg({"time": {'Mean': 'mean', 'var': 'var'}})\
    ['time'].sort_values(by='Mean', ascending=False).sort_index(level='time_window', sort_remaining=False)
highest_5_mean = df_to_join.groupby(['time_window']).head(5).copy()
highest_5_mean.reset_index(inplace=True)
highest_5_mean.rename(columns={'time': 'Mean'}, inplace=True)

dataset_filtered = pd.merge(mo_finaldf, highest_5_mean, how='inner', left_on=['time_window', 'tap'],
                            right_on=['time_window', 'ID'])
sns.catplot(x='time_window', hue='tap', y='time', data=dataset_filtered, kind="box",
                 showfliers=False)
```